# Excel VBA continually returning 0

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to calculate a cross currency rate by simply summing the forex rates for A/B and B/C and multiplying the means to find the A/C rate and I keep getting 0 in return. This is the code:

```
Function forex(audData As Range, euData As Range)

    a = Application.Count(audData)
    e = Application.Count(euData)
    'Counts how many values are in the data

    aSum = 0
    eSum = 0
    aMean = 0
    eMean = 0

    For i = 1 To aud ' This sums the 1st forex rate and finds the mean
        aSum = aSum + audData(i)
    Next i

    aMean = aSum / a

    For i = 1 To eu ' This sums the 2nd forex rate and finds the mean
        eSum = eSum + euData(i)
    Next i

    eMean = eSum / e

    forex = (aMean * eMean)

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `Average()` function:

```
Function forex(audData As Range, euData As Range)
    With WorksheetFunction
        forex = .Average(audData) * .Average(euData)
    End With  
End Function
```

Comment: This is both shorter and faster than what OP was trying to do, though they still need to be made aware of the dangers of using undeclared variables, so I'll keep my more verbose answer, although this is clearly superior.

Comment: @ArenGallagher, did you get through it?

Comment: @ArenGallagher, any chance to get feedback from you?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be a victim of undeclared variables. You have two loops,

```
For i = 1 To aud
```

and (later on)

```
For i = 1 To eu
```

where neither `aud` nor `eu` are declared. Thus, they default to variants with an implicit value of `0`, hence neither of these loops ever execute and all your variables stay at `0`.

You really should get in the habit of using `Option Explicit` at the top of all of your modules. This can be done automatically by enabling the option `Require Variable Declarations` in the VBA editor options. In the long run, it will save you hours of debugging time.

I can't test your code, but if you declare your variables and replace `aud` and `eu` by what I think you meant you would get:

```
Function forex(audData As Range, euData As Range) As Double
   Dim a As Long, e As Long, aSum As Double, eSum As Double, aMean As Double, eMean As Double, i As Long
    a = Application.Count(audData)
    e = Application.Count(euData)
    'Counts how many values are in the data

    For i = 1 To a ' This sums the 1st forex rate and finds the mean
        aSum = aSum + audData(i)
    Next i

    aMean = aSum / a

    For i = 1 To e ' This sums the 2nd forex rate and finds the mean
        eSum = eSum + euData(i)
    Next i

    eMean = eSum / e

    forex = (aMean * eMean)

End Function
```

I skipped the lines like `aSum = 0` since properly declared VBA variables have reasonable default values.

Comment: I think the OP has even more problems by using a loop than you have noticed - i.e. if some cells within `audData` or `euData` are empty then the `Count` will be less than the number of cells, and the loop will only iterate over the first `a` or `e` cells (even though that will potentially include empty cells) and will ignore some of the final cells in the range.  (It probably should be `audData.Count` instead of `Application.Count(audData)`, with an appropriate `If Not IsEmpty(..) Then` in the loop.)  But +1 for pointing out the merits of `Option Explicit`!